# Rails/SQL no results show from Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Versions: CENTOS7, mysql2('>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'), rails('4.2.6')

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= section.course_id %></td>
        <td><%= section.term_id %></td>
        <td><%= section.user_id %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

**sections controller**

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_account!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @sections =  User.find_by_account_id(current_user).courses
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

**createSections migration**

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.integer :course_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :terms do |t|
      t.integer :term_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.belongs_to :course, index: true
      t.belongs_to :term, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**course.rb model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :sections
has_many :terms, :through => :sections
```

**term.rb model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :sections
has_many :courses, :through => :sections
```

**section.rb model**

```
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :term
belongs_to :user
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :sections
has_many :courses, :through => :sections
has_many :terms, :through => :sections
```

- Expected result: List the current(logged in) user's courses/terms/ID
- Current result: blank

This is my first time working with rails and SO, I tried changing the relationships a few times to see if anything would change but not sure how to approach this. I have tried using ActiveRecord:Associations as a reference.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You are assigning `@sections = current_user.courses` – did you mean `@sections = current_user.sections`?

Comment: I like how you described your problem by the way :thumbsup:

Comment: I get an undefined method 'sections', NoMethodError for doing this, did I miss/forget to write a method somewhere & thank you, first time using SO, tried to follow by example.

Comment: Why are you querying for a user when you already have the user `current_user`?

Comment: Maybe I mistook my intentions, what I want to happen when I load my /sections page is for the current logged in user's "results" to show, ie. where his user_id matches course_id, term_id.  For example, a teacher would teach some courses, this would show the teacher which classes they are teaching in this page, along with the terms.

Comment: Please show the full error message. Just the error class itself does not contain very much info. If the full error message reads `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sections' for nil:NilClass` then your `current_user` is not set. How do you authenticate the current user. Did you implement `authenticate_account!` yourself? How?

Comment: NoMethodError in SectionsController#index
undefined method `sections' for nil:NilClass, 
error @     @sections = current_user.sections

I did not create the authenticate_account myself, I defined current_user in the application_controller.rb as 
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

Comment: So `current_user` is `nil`. You probably need to fix your login first. Check the documentation of whatever implements `authenticate_account!` for that. hth gtg hf&gl

Answer (score 0):

If you already have current_user then you can just call the related models directly.

```
@sections =  User.find_by_account_id(current_user).courses

to 

@sections =  current_user.courses
```

Comment: So if I have:    def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end?

Comment: If you are using devise current_user is already available, if you doing authentication manually yes, you have to define current_user method.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to address is that you typically want separate migrations for each distinct `thing` that you're migrating.  It's a convention that helps you keep fine-grained control over your changes, and it helps keep your migrations clean.

Sometimes, though, you actually want to have a "mass" migration.  You have a mass-migration here.  In the mass-migration circumstance, the migration name should reflect the combined purpose, so you'd want to name it something like `CreateCoreTables`; `CreateSections` is too narrow a name for creating multiple tables.  You will also need to change the name of the migration file to be `2016XXXXXXXX_create_core_tables.rb`, where `XXXXXXXXX` is left as the previous value.

Next, you'll want to correct your use of keys (the `_id` columns), as these are improperly declaring the association fields, which will cause the associations to not work (or work incorrectly).

Instead, you want something like this:

class CreateCoreTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

```
create_table :terms do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :users do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :sections do |t|
  t.integer :user_id, null: false
  t.integer :term_id, null: false
  t.integer :course_id, null: false
  t.timestamps
end
```

end
end

It's difficult to tell what the actual intended relationships are from the code provided.  It would be worth reading on [Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to make sure that you understand what relationships you intend, and how to describe them.  While you're working out the migrations, keep revisiting the model relationships, as well.  These are the bedrock of the application, so you want to spend time getting them right.

Remember, for ActiveRecord relationships, these rules will guide you:

- If a model *owns* another model, use `has_many` or `has_one`
- In the *owned* model, use `belongs_to`
- If a model needs *access* to another model (but doesn't own it), use a `has_many`, `:through` relationship
- Models cannot have `has_many` or `has_one` relationships directly to each other; you need an intermediate table in that case with the requisite `belongs_to` for each of the other tables

Once you have the migrations and relationships worked out, you can move on to the query.  You can use [Rails Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to optimize the query to retrieve the associations at the same time.  This will address your current functional needs, and prevent an [N+1 query](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) issue at the same time.

```
@sections =  Section.joins(courses: :terms).where(user: current_user)
```

When you have retrieved `@sections`, you can do these types of actions to get the data that you want.  The `courses` and `terms` members are collections, and you can interact with them as though they were arrays:

```
@sections.each do |section|
  puts "Section: #{section.id}"

  puts "Number of user sections: #{@sections.courses.length}"
  section.courses.each do |course|
    puts "Course: #{course.id}"
  end

  puts "Number of user terms: #{@sections.terms.length}"
  @sections.terms do |term|
    puts "Term: #{term.id}"
  end

  puts "User's email: #{@sections.user.email}"
end
```

Once you've mastered these, you've got the basics of Rails.  Work on one model/controller at a time to keep from overcomplicating the work; you can always add on more once once component is working like you expect.  Always make sure that you have your foundation working before you move onto new aspects of the app that will depend on it.

Also, remember to use the Rails guides.  They're very helpful, so keep them on hand at all times while you're learning.  SO is also a great resource, and make sure that you ask pointed questions, so that you can get direct answers.